# SwtichToContext does not return to original thread

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, f#

I'm working with an API that can only access its objects on the main thread, so I need to create a new thread to be used for my GUI and then swap back to the original thread for any lengthy calculations involving the API.

So far I have the following code:

```
[<EntryPoint; STAThread>]
let main _ =
    Debug.WriteLine($"[{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] - Inital thread")
    let initCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current
            
    let uiThread = new Thread(fun () ->
        let guiCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current
        Debug.WriteLine($"[{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] - New UI thread")
        async{
            do! Async.SwitchToContext initCtx
            Debug.WriteLine($"[{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] - Back to initial thread")
            // Lengthy API calculation here
            do! Async.SwitchToContext guiCtx
            Debug.WriteLine($"[{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] - Back to UI thread")

        } |> Async.RunSynchronously        
    )
    uiThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    uiThread.Start()
    1
```

However when I run this I get the output:

```
[1] - Inital thread
[4] - New UI thread
[5] - Back to initial thread
[5] - Back to UI thread
```

So it doesn't seem to be switching contexts the way I would expect.  How can I switch back to the original thread after creating a new thread this way?

I have tried calling
`SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher))` first to ensure that the original thread has a valid `SynchronizationContext` but that causes the program to exit at the `Async.SwitchToContext` lines without throwing any exception.

I have also tried using `Async.StartImmediate` instead of `RunSynchronously` with the same result.

If I try both of these at the same time then the program just freezes up at the `Async.SwitchToContext` lines instead of exiting out.

Comment: http://tomasp.net/blog/async-non-blocking-gui.aspx/

Comment: That's one of the articles that I was reading through when trying to do this, but how come when I call `Async.SwitchToContext initCtx` it doesn't take me back to thread 1?

Comment: I would expect SynchronizationContext.Current to be null at the point you grab it.

Comment: I've tried calling `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher))` first, which I believe will set `SynchronizationContext.Current`, but if I do that then it will never reach the 3rd debug statement, the program seems to just hang at the SwitchToContext line

Comment: I think another potential problem is that your main thread is just going to finish anyway, so there is no way to go back to it. Why do you want to structure your code this way? Normally the main thread will be the GUI thread.

Comment: This code is being run as a plugin for an existing application, and the application's API requires that its objects be accessed by the main thread.  So any lengthy calculations I do using the API would freeze the UI unless I can create a new thread to run the UI on

Comment: Right, but you seem to be trying to make your worker thread a UI thread. I say that because you set the apartment state on it, and you call it "uiThread". The calling application is certainly going to require its objects to be accessed on its GUI thread, which in your case (I presume) is the thread that main is called on.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure of any other way of going about it.  You're correct that main is being called on the external application's GUI thread, but if I want to display my own window and do calculations on these API objects using this external application's GUI thread, then I need to create my own GUI thread to prevent locking up my window, no?

Comment: I'm not that much of an expert, but I've been thinking that switching back to a context doesn't necessarily mean you get back to the same thread. Don't know if that is true is some cases, all cases, or no cases.

Comment: In WPF and WinForms, you don't create your own GUI thread. It's created for you. From there you create your other worker threads, or tasks or whatever.